# Ползёт и перекрывается логотип

Tags: дефект, дизайн, анонимный-пользователь

Если выйти из аккаунта и зайти на страницу любого участника, логотип слегка сдвигается вниз и обрезается (актуально и для Меты).

[image: скриншот]

UPD: похоже, в Мете для этой странички разные логотипы для авторизованного человека и гостя.

Comment: Не нужно выходить из аккаунта, достаточно открыть в приватном режиме :) Ну и это надо бы на MSE.

Comment: Позволил себе [перевести на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324475/339911)

Comment: Оказалось, что проблема известна уже как более четырёх месяцев. Видимо, ещё пару лет просуществует.